# Is it possible that a fillable field in Laravel can be hacked?

Tags: laravel, security, mass-assignment

```
class Student extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [‘first_name’, ‘last_name’, ‘email’];
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@kshitij206/laravel-mass-assignment-guarded-or-fillable-7c3a64b49ca6

Everywhere on the Internet, they say to use `fillable` or `guarded` for security in Laravel.

But **if a field is fillable, then, can this field be hacked?**

Comment: You should read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I read that, and I'm still not sure of what can happen with a fillable field.

Comment: @Alex01 If you assign a field to the fillable array, it means that when you pass an array to `Model::create()` method, the keys of that array must match the attribute names of the model. So if you mean "inserted" by "hacked", then yes, because you've decidedly allowed that. As long as you are using `$request->only()` instead of `$request->all()`, you should be fine.

Comment: @Tanmay I see!
And if I don't store an array. But only something like:
`$user->user_type = 'admin';
$user->save();`
There is no problem of security?

Comment: It depends on where the value 'admin' is coming from. If you are receiving it from an HTTP request parameter, then yes it's a security issue. To reiterate, `$user->type = 'admin'` <-- No problem. `$user->type = $request->type` <-- Problem. Normally you would not receive the parameter through HTTP request and you would not directly assign the request param.

Comment: Alright, thank you! For `$user->type = $request->type` <-- Problem. It's only an XSS issue, right?

Comment: @Tanmay For `$user->type = $request->type` <-- Problem. My question is in a nutshell: If I'm **NOT** using an array: Data can only be inserted **on this field**? Or is it possible that Data sent from a user can be inserted on other fields?

Comment: @Alex01 If you are not using array, which means you are manually picking which $request param to add, then only those $request params will be added, which means if the user sends extra params or unwanted params, they will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

All Eloquent models are protected against mass-assignment by default, so to use mass assignment, you should specify a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on the model to use the `create` method to save a new model in a single line.

So the code below, should cause an error

```php
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10', 'number' => 3]);
```

when you have

```php
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

Because you cannot mass assign the `number` property here.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment